# Azure pipeline defaults to wrong agent

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have the following problem: I have specified a pipeline yaml which runs on a self-hosted agent for the first stage. For the second stage I haven't declared an agent. It should default to a Microsoft-hosted agent (*and does for all other pipelines with the same syntax and use-case*). However, when initializing the agent at execution time, the chosen agent is of the self-hosted variety.
I've tried creating a fork, deleting the repo and re-initializing it. Both to no avail.
When I specify an agent for the stage, like so (as described in this ms [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)):

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
```

I get the following message:
 `There was a resource authorization issue: "The pipeline is not valid. Could not find a pool with name Azure Pipelines. The pool does not exist or has not been authorized for use. For authorization details, refer to https://aka.ms/yamlauthz."`
When I click authorize resources, I get the message that it was successful. However, the authorization issue keeps returning.

**azure-pipeline.yaml**

```
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: templates
      type: git
      name: azure-devops-reusable-tasks

variables:
  - group: mijnverzekeringsvoorwaarden-api-service_ONT # for deployments (build scripts only target ONT)
  - template: add-variable-branch-name.yml@templates

name: 1.0.0$(branchName)-$(Build.BuildId)

stages:
  - stage: Build
    displayName: Build
    jobs:
      - job: Build
        displayName: Build
        pool:
          name: Default
          demands: companyName.Docker
        steps:
          - template: maven.yml@templates
          - publish: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
            artifact: mijnverzekeringsvoorwaarden-api-service
          - template: publish-surefire-test-results.yml@templates
          - template: publish-jacoco-code-coverage.yml@templates
          - template: git-set-version-tag.yml@templates

  - stage: Scan
    dependsOn: Build
    jobs:
      - job: Scan
        displayName: Dependency scan
        steps:
          - template: owasp-scan.yml@templates
```

And this is the template in question being called for the second stage. The one that is supposed to run on a MS-hosted machine:

**owasp-scan.yml@templates**

```
steps:
  - download: current
  - task: dependency-check-build-task@6
    displayName: Owasp dependency check
    inputs:
        projectName: $(Build.Repository.Name)
        scanPath: $(Pipeline.Workspace)
        format: 'HTML'
```

Any insight as to why it is defaulting to the wrong pool for this particular pipeline?

**Update:**
Added a screen shot of the agent pools and agents in the microsoft hosted pool.
Tried referencing the agent pool with the name given in the screenshot, like so:

```
pool:
  name: 'Hosted Ubuntu 1604'
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
```

This gives the following error:
`##[error]No agent found in pool Hosted Ubuntu 1604 which satisfies the following demand: ubuntu-latest. All demands: ubuntu-latest, Agent.Version -gtVersion 2.188.2`

When using:

```
pool:
  name: 'Hosted Ubuntu 1604'
  vmImage: 'Hosted Ubuntu 1604 2'
```

I get:  `Encountered error(s) while parsing pipeline YAML: /azure-pipelines.yml (Line: 37, Col: 20): Invalid demand 'Hosted Ubuntu 1604 2'. The demand should be in the format '<NAME>' to test existence, and '<NAME> -equals <VALUE>' to test for a specific value. For example, 'VISUALSTUDIO' or 'agent.os -equals Windows_NT'.`

[image: Agent pool]

[image: Agents in MS hosted pool]

**Update 2:**
I compared projects. Another project did have the Azure Pipelines agent pool. I approved this project (the one which has the issue) to also have access to this pool. When I explicitly define it in the yaml, it uses this (cloud hosted) pool. However, when I provide no pool information it keeps defaulting to the self-hosted variant. To re-iterate, this only happens for this particular pipeline.

Comment: Hi, can you show the screen shot of the agent pool?

Comment: what about change `name: Default` to `name: Azure Pipelines`?

Comment: That pool, Azure Pipelines, doesn't exists. See screenshot.

Comment: The pool does exists in other projects within the same organization. See update 2 for more info @1_1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been circumvented. When explicitly defining the agent from the agent pool, with correct nomenclature, it does pick an agent from this pool.
However, this does not explain why this behavior is exhibited for this pipeline, while all other pipelines pick an agent from the same pool without defining this. These default to this (the same) pool.

In this specific case the hack is defining the pool like so:

```
pool:
  name: 'Hosted Ubuntu 1604'
```

Answer (score 1):

> Any insight as to why it is defaulting to the wrong pool for this particular pipeline?

You could try to change the value in the Default agent pool for YAML to **Azure Pipelines** in the UI:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the input Leo. I only have the default option in the dropdown though.

Comment: @MyName, oddly. You mean there is no Hosted agent? If yes, would you please update your question with images about it and image about the Project Settings->Agent pools->Azure Pipelines->Agents.

Comment: There is a hosted agent in the pool. In other pipelines when I don't choose any agent, it defaults to this. In the dropdown however, there is just the one option. @Leo Liu-MSFT. I've updated the original post.

Comment: Perhaps I should delete the MSFT hosted pool and try again? It should provision automatically, right? @Leo Liu-MSFT

Comment: According to the image you provided, it seems the agent pools **Default** and **Hosted Ubuntu 1604** are self hosted agent pool. Do you have any other agent pools?

Comment: The Hosted Ubuntu one is the cloud hosted one as far as I know. It even has a symbol of a cloud next to it (which I didn't put there). This are all the pools. When running any other pipeline, without defining a pool, it retrieves a microsoft hosted machine at runtime.

Comment: @MyName, This is not the same as what we showed. Please try to use `pool:
  name: 'Hosted Ubuntu 1604'` without `vmImage: 'Hosted Ubuntu 1604 2'`. We could not specify the agent directly. If you want specify one socify agent, you need use demands

Comment: This works @Leo Liu-MSFT. When provisioning I see output, `provisioning agent from the cloud.` This is more of a hack, seeing as how other pipelines default to this agent pool.

Comment: @MyName, Glad to know that work for you. For your question in your updated2, what is the value in your **Default agent pool for YAML** option?

Comment: The default option under the heading Hosted, is-> **Hosted Ubuntu 1604**. Since adding the agent (azure pipelines) pool as described, this is now also an option under the Hosted section. It seems that all pipelines default to this hosted ubuntu version. Which is the (a) MSFT-hosted pool with a weird name?

Comment: @MyName, If you do not specify the agent pool in the YAML pipeline, it will use the default agent **Hosted Ubuntu 1604**

Comment: Yes. And in this specific case, that fails and it takes an agent from our self-hosted pool. I've switched the option to be **azure pipelines**. It works as expected now. Even when not defining an agent pool.

Comment: @MyName, So, have all your problems been solved? If not, please let me know the latest question for you, I will keep help you.